# handling exceptions or errors in shell scripting

Tags: shell, unix, error-handling, exception

I have a code module in which I will be checking for errors using the "$?" in shell scripting. Assume the following scenario:

```
"sub_script.sh"
--error statements--
echo "abc"

"main_script.sh"
sh sub_script.sh
if [ $? == 0 ];then
 echo "no error"
else
 echo "error"
fi
```

Now, even if I have error statements in the `sub_script.sh` if I trigger the script from the `main_script.sh` I can't handle it because I have an `echo` statement which runs successfully and returns 0 value.

I just replicated this here I have many shell scripts which run a hive or spark or some other code.

Is there any change to handle this kind of scenario in shell scripting?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you can put the `$?` result in a variable and check it in your if statement

Answer (score 0):

It is up to you to return the correct exit code from your scripts in all cases. If your script fails but exits with `0` (success) due to an echo statement, the script is buggy and should be fixed.

Use `exit 1` (or any value 1-255) to exit with failure, or `exit 0` to exit with success.